# Understanding SVD for positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that

$$
M = EE^\top
$$
where $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ is full rank.

$M$ can also be expressed in terms of a Singular value decomposition:

$$
M = USU^\top
$$

Can I say that the vector space generated by the columns of $U$ is the same of the one generated by the columns of $E$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that in your version of SVD, $U$ is $n \times k$ and $S$ is $k \times k$.

Indeed, the column space of $U$ is identical to the column space of $E$.